# Use MediaWiki's internal cache to save bad login attempts

Tags: caching, mediawiki

I'm working on a MediaWiki plugin that adds a certain captcha if users have more than three bad login attempts. I'm basing this on the existing [ConfirmEdit](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aConfirmEdit) plugin but for some reason the way they store bad login attempts doesn't seem to work for me. After checking the code they use, it seems they're using the global variable `$wgMemc`, which in my case appears to be an instance of `FakeMemchachedClient`. This is a fake memchache that just returns true on everything without even saving anything.

I'm trying to find out how to implement another way to internally keep track of the amount of bad logins, preferrably without having to consult the database for this.

The only thing I could come up with that avoids the cache entirely is POSTing the amount of bad logins, but this could easily be modified by a smart user/bot...

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ideal case, `$wgMemc` should be instance of `MemcachedPhpBagOStuff`. It is actually an interface to memcached, see the [MediaWiki page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Memcached) about it for more information and usage in MediaWiki.

For this use case it would be great choice. However, since it seems you don’t have memcached set up, the only viable alternative is probably using the database.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I think it's a bit too much to enable memcached just for this, so I'll just use the database then :)